Ubuntu ssh login welcome message displaying wrong root partition size after partition/filesystem expansion
I've been running a Dell Wyse 5010 (AMD dual core, 8GB Sata Dom and 8G Ram) as a NAS for home for a while, and just replaced it today with a 7020 (AMD quad core, 16GB ram and 60GB SSD)
I cloned the drive from the old system, used Parted to resize the root partition and successfully resized the LVM, and added a swap partition. The root partition was filling up before, so updates were failing etc.
But on login, the Ubuntu welcome message is still referencing the old disk size: " / is using 93.3% of 5.78GB", even though df -h is showing / as being 39G and updates are now working, (after a -fix-broken-system)
Is there something I missed? The box has been rebooted multiple times since the FS expansion, mostly because the ethernet card obviously changed.
Is that welcome message not updating the size of root going to cause a problem later when the drive fills up more, and goes over 100% (of the old size) full, or is it just cosmetic? And if not cosmetic, can anyone point me at what to do to fix it?
Thanks
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-107-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/pro

System information as of Tue May 14 04:04:51 PM UTC 2024

System load:  0.85546875        Processes:               153
Usage of /:   93.3% of 5.78GB   Users logged in:         0
Memory usage: 3%                IPv4 address for enp1s0: 192.168.1.4
Swap usage:   0%

=> / is using 93.3% of 5.78GB




mark@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              1.6G  2.7M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   39G  5.0G   33G  14% /
tmpfs                              7.6G  3.9M  7.6G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          974M  253M  654M  28% /boot
/dev/sda1                          511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000


I think you only have a cosmetic issue since the df -h output is correct and reflects the real situation. The information in the welcome screen comes from /var/lib/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.cache . Check if that file is properly updated upon boot/login time i.e. with ls -lah /var/lib/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.cache . If not something might be wrong with /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo for instance not executable. You can tranform this to comment if it doesn't help you find the source of the issue but that is where I would start looking.

Thank you for that info, landscape-sysinfo is executable and does display the correct info, so I'm not sure why sysinfo.cache isn't being updated, but I'm happy to leave this at this point.
Thanks again.
landscape-sysinfo gives:  Usage of /:   12.9% of 38.76GB

You might want to delete the /var/lib/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.cache file to see if it get's recreated properly?
